# ETIMEDOUT error while perform a get operation using express and node.js with basic auth

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to get some data from an external url inside my project (angular2 server side). I am always getting the ETIMEDOUT error. This is my code

```
 var request = require('request');

 var username = "username",
        password = "pwd",
        url = "myURL",
        auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

    request(
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": auth
            }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('Error: '+error);
            console.log('Response: '+response);
            console.log('Body: '+body);
        }
    );
```